# How to configure NeoVim Treesitter in VimScript?

Tags: neovim, treesitter

I'm trying to configure treesitter syntax highlighting for my neovim config but the docs only show examples with Lua and i am using Vimscript. If you're using VimScript they redirect you to an example of calling a Lua function within VimScript but I don't understand how it works.

From their docs:

> Following examples assume that you are configuring neovim with lua. If you are using vimscript, see `:help lua-heredoc`. All modules are disabled by default and need to be activated explicitly in your init.lua, e.g., via
>
> lua-heredoc:
>
> ```
>       Executes Lua script {script} from within Vimscript. {endmarker} must NOT
>       be preceded by whitespace. You can omit [endmarker] after the "<<" and use
>       a dot "." after {script} (similar to |:append|, |:insert|).
>   
>       Example: >
>           function! CurrentLineInfo()
>           lua << EOF
>           local linenr = vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)[1]
>           local curline = vim.api.nvim_buf_get_lines(
>                   0, linenr - 1, linenr, false)[1]
>           print(string.format("Current line [%d] has %d bytes",
>                   linenr, #curline))
>           EOF
>           endfunction
>
>        Note that the `local` variables will disappear when the block finishes.
>        But not globals.
> ```

I'd like to make this Lua code work in VimScript:

```lua
require("nvim-treesitter.configs").setup({
    ensure_installed = { "javascript", "typescript", "lua", "vim", "json", "html", "rust", "tsx" },
    sync_install = false,
    auto_install = true,
    highlight = {
        enable = true,
    },
})
```

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following to any `.vim` file which will be loaded:

```
lua << EOF
require("nvim-treesitter.configs").setup({
    ensure_installed = { "javascript", "typescript", "lua", "vim", "json", "html", "rust", "tsx" },
    sync_install = false,
    auto_install = true,
    highlight = {
        enable = true,
    },
})
EOF
```

and it'll be normally called as if you'd be in a lua file. You can imagine that as a wrapper vor neovim which says at `lua << EOF`: "Ok bro, after this line, there'll be lua code and **not** vimscript stuff. Got it?" and if it reaches the bottom `EOF`: "Alright, the input for the `lua` command ends here. We can keep going after this line with vimscript!"

### Other example

Take a look into that as an example:

```
lua << EOF
print("Hello from lua")
EOF
```

If you open up neovim in a new file now then you can see a `Hello from lua` in your messages (`:msg`).

### (Opiniated) Recommondation

I highly recommend to use an extra lua file where you write your lua-code to avoid those "wrappers" (`lua << EOF` and `EOF`) in your config file which makes it more readable in my opinion.